# How to get git branch information supplied by vim-fugitive asynchronously for my statusline?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, statusline, async

I can directly use the following approach to get the git branch information:

```
...
let l:git = "%6*%{exists('g:loaded_fugitive')?fugitive#statusline():''}%*"
...
```

If so, it can cause a delay to the startup of vim, I guess tens to a hundred milliseconds. With the async feature in Vim8, can I get this asynchronously? I am not conversant with this feature, could someone give me some tips? A mini example would be better, thanks!

Comment: The only things that can be run asynchronously are external processes. We cannot run VimL functions nor vim commands asynchronously. I'm afraid you'll have to run `git branch|grep...` asynchronously, and when the result comes back inject it into the statusline before refreshing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform asynchronous tasks from Vim, people generally recommend using the [`vim-dispatch`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin to run external processes in the background and call back later.

But since I don't have an example for that, I'm going to offer some dirty synchronous tricks instead...

---

You could consider only doing the work when the user has gone idle, by waiting for the `CursorHold` event.

```
let g:git_status = "..."

let &statusline = "blah blah %{g:git_status} blah blah"

augroup Get_Git_Status
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorHold * let g:git_status = fugitive#statusline()
augroup END
```

Add an identical `CursorHoldI` line, if you also want the updates to happen when you are idle in Insert mode.

---

Alternatively, but slightly longer, I call a function to [cache the value](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/7502887c0e3a995a6971fcfe0b8cac6acaf6e50d/.vim/plugin/vimbuddy.vim#L46-L134) and only update it once every 10 seconds.  You could adapt that to call `fugitive#statusline()`.  And you could, by storing a timestamp at startup, only allow polling after Vim has been open for a few seconds.

---

I do not recall right now when and why `statusline` gets evaluated, or how frequently.

A combination of `CursorHold` *and* caching would probably have the least noticeable impact on Vim's performance.  Although just fetching the git branch is not that heavy a task anyway, especially after the first time.

For heavier work, for example checking the status of the entire working tree, I really would recommend a separate "dispatched" process.